# How to achieve enum names like Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea

Tags: c++, qt, enums

When using Qt, many functions take an argument like the flag Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea.

Even though I looked through the Qt sources I could not understand how to achieve
this naming behaviour. Is it general C++ or Qt specific?

Assume I have a class **MyClass**:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();
        void setFlag(???);
};
```

I want to call the setFlag method like this:

```
MyClass mc;
mc.setFlag(MyClass::flag1 | MyClass::flag2)
```

flag1 and flag2 should just be 0x01 & 0x02, is this an enum?
Where do I have to declare that?
And what is the argument of the method?

I'm sorry if this is obvious, but I don't get it.

**SOLUTION (from the answers)**

Very good. From reading the answers below I added this:
(note that I didn't really needed flags, just the numbers from an enum, this simplified it a lot)

```
namespace MyNames {
    typedef enum {
        FA = 0,
        FB = 1
    } Field;
}

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        char getField(MyNames::Field f) const;
};
```

This indeed allows the following calls (not):

```
mc.getField(MyNames::FA) //OK
mc.getField(1)           //not OK
```

Comment: Your solution, however, does not have the flag behavior of the Qt flags. It solves an entirely different problem.

Comment: True. I'm really sorry for that. That was my mistake when writing the question for flags. I would happily expand the solution to include binary operators for the enums. (Their value can easily be changed to 0x01, 0x02, 0x04...)

Comment: But your input argument type can no longer be simply MyNames::Field if you want to allow OR-combinations of MyNames::Field enum values, even though you can re-define their values easily. E.g. mc.getField(MyNames::FA | MyNames::FB); will fail if you only re-define FA = 0x01 and FB = 0x02.

Comment: If you know how to do it, I would be happy if you could explain it in an answer - we could improve the solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this (or something similar) in `src\corelib\global\qnamespace.h`:

```
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
namespace
#else
class Q_CORE_EXPORT
#endif
Qt {
```

This usually becomes simply

```
namespace Qt {
```

To refer to a name declared inside this `Qt` namespace (such as `LeftDockWidgetArea`), you precede it with `Qt::`.

Comment: Alright. So I add the namespace. What do I have to declare IN the namespace to get Qt::something?

Comment: Anything. In this case, `enum DockWidgetArea { LeftDockWidgetArea,...} ;`

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the definition of `Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea`:

```
enum DockWidgetArea {
    LeftDockWidgetArea = 0x1,
    RightDockWidgetArea = 0x2,
    TopDockWidgetArea = 0x4,
    BottomDockWidgetArea = 0x8,

    DockWidgetArea_Mask = 0xf,
    AllDockWidgetAreas = DockWidgetArea_Mask,
    NoDockWidgetArea = 0
};

Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(DockWidgetAreas, DockWidgetArea)
```

Note the `Q_DECLARE_FLAGS` macro which, by creating a `QFlags` typedef achieves the behavior you are asking about. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qflags.html#Q_DECLARE_FLAGS.

Comment: Note that C++ is strongly typed and doesn't automatically overload `operator|` for enums. `LeftDockWidgetArea | RightDockWidgetArea` requires an `DockWidgetArea operator|(DockWidgetArea, DockWidgetArea)`

Comment: MSalters: enum Foo { Hello }; enum Bar { World }; ... int x = Hello|World; works just fine.

Comment: Just in case someone is wondering: The operator MSalters talks about, can easily be declared via Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(MyFlags)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Qt documentation carefully ( http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qt.html#DockWidgetArea-enum for your particular case), you will see that Qt uses a templated QFlags class to store OR-combinations of enum values in a type-safe manner.

EDIT: Looks like there are two kinds of answers because your question is not very clear. Upon reading your question carefully, I think the following is what you want.

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        enum Flags{
            Flag1 = 0x01,
            Flag2 = 0x02
        }
        MyClass();
        void setFlag(int Flags);//Not type-safe but works.
        void setFlag(Flags<MyClass::Flags> Flags);//Type-safe but you have to create a Flags class yourself
};
```

More explanation can be found in an old question here:
[How to use enums as flags in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448396/how-to-use-enums-as-flags-in-c)

Comment: There's no need to create a custom class manually. See Q_DECLARE_FLAGS in hc_'s answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, provided he is actually using Qt library in his project and not just trying to emulate Qt library code with his own code.

Comment: I indeed want to emulate it in pure C++. I edited my question to include your enum, now how to make the method typesafe?

Comment: HWende: Sorry. I'm no expert in templates and such so I cannot give a solid answer to this. I was simply suggesting that you try to do the same as in the Qt library by referring to their source code.