# Is this C++ [out] parameter a pointer to an enumeration, or just a single value?

Tags: c++, enums, directshow, directshow.net

Currently I'm working with [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/), an unofficial .NET "port" for Microsoft's DirectShow (C++).

Both [IAMAnalogVideoDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389102(v=vs.85).aspx) and [IAMTVTuner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375974(v=vs.85).aspx) declare the method `get_AvailableVideoFormats`. This is how the method is defined in the official docs:

```
HRESULT get_AvailableTVFormats(
  [out]  long *lAnalogVideoStandard
);
```

It's not clear to me if this parameter is a pointer to a single `AnalogVideoStandard`, or a enumeration. Unfortunatelly I'm too inexperienced with C++ to fully understand the docs. Because of the methods name, I would expect it to be a enumeration, but is it?

The reason I'm asking this, is because in the .NET library, this parameter is not a enumeration, just a single value. I find this very strange, since I'm expecting to get multiple "available video formats" here.

---

By the way, `AnalogVideoStandard` is an enum.

Comment: Look at the [MSDN article about C# enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc138362.aspx), particularly the bit about "Enumeration types as bit flags".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's not clear to me if this parameter is a pointer to a single AnalogVideoStandard, or a enumeration.

It's neither<sup>1</sup>:

> Pointer to a variable that receives a bitwise OR of zero or more flags from the AnalogVideoStandard enumeration.

It's a pointer to a value that represents zero or more `AnalogVideoStandard`s.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448396/how-to-use-enums-as-flags-in-c) should explain the rest. You should be able to apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute) to your .NET code.

<sup>1</sup> Technically it could be *an* enumeration value in C# because `enum` types can have a `FlagsAttribute` applied to them but there's no equivalent in C++, you just `|` values together with no special fanfare.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why DirectShow used `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...` as enum values. Now I know why. Those links were very helpful, thanks! Just one question though. Do you happen to know how to enumerate through all `AnalogVideoStandard` in this pointer?