# Define values that can be combined

Tags: c++, enums

I would like to define an enum with different states that can be combined.
I found that I could use bitset but I am not sure about how I can combine them.

So here is my enum :

```
enum Mode {
  NONE = 0,
  MODE_1 = 1 << 0,
  MODE_2 = 1 << 1,
  MODE_3 = 1 << 2
};
```

And what I want to do is to have a value that includes for instance mode_1 and mode_2.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? This *is* how you define bit flags.

Comment: Let's say I have a function with parameter Mode. If I want to call this function with this parameter set to a value that corresponds to MODE_1 and MODE_2, how can I do this ?

Comment: @klaus Supposed you have a function declaration like `void foo(uint8_t modes);` you'll call it like `foo(MODE_1 | MODE_2);`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : thank you - and is it better to define the header like I did or like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448396/how-to-use-enums-as-flags-in-c ?

Comment: @klaus Read the duplicate to get known all of the relevant information.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ For type safety it would be better to have `void foo(Mode modes)` which could be achieved by overloading bitwise operators as suggested in the duplicate.

Comment: @zett42 Yes, that's correct. I just wanted to give a short example.

Comment: @klaus See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/