# Why did I have to use an int to combine these enum flag values together?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, com, enum-flags

Perhaps someone can just explain the logic behind why this is actually an issue.

In my C# DLL I have a set of flag values that  expose via the COM API:

```
[Flags]
[Guid("~~~")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public enum AssignmentType
{
    None = 0,
    Attendant = 1,
    ConductorCBS = 2,
    ReaderCBS = 4,
    Chairman = 8,
    Mike = 16,
    PlatformAttendant = 32,
    Prayer = 64,
    OCLM = 128,
    Sound = 256,
    Student = 512,
    Custom = 1024,
    Demonstration = 2048,
    Assistant = 4096,
    Host = 8192,
    CoHost = 16384,
    OCLMTreasures = 32768,
    OCLMGems = 65536,
    OCLMLiving = 131072,
    StudentBibleReading = 262144,
    StudentDiscussion = 524288,
    StudentTalk = 1048576
}
```

In my C++ MFC project, the above is exposed as follows:

```
enum __declspec(uuid("~~~"))
AssignmentType
{
    AssignmentType_None = 0,
    AssignmentType_Attendant = 1,
    AssignmentType_ConductorCBS = 2,
    AssignmentType_ReaderCBS = 4,
    AssignmentType_Chairman = 8,
    AssignmentType_Mike = 16,
    AssignmentType_PlatformAttendant = 32,
    AssignmentType_Prayer = 64,
    AssignmentType_OCLM = 128,
    AssignmentType_Sound = 256,
    AssignmentType_Student = 512,
    AssignmentType_Custom = 1024,
    AssignmentType_Demonstration = 2048,
    AssignmentType_Assistant = 4096,
    AssignmentType_Host = 8192,
    AssignmentType_CoHost = 16384,
    AssignmentType_OCLMTreasures = 32768,
    AssignmentType_OCLMGems = 65536,
    AssignmentType_OCLMLiving = 131072,
    AssignmentType_StudentBibleReading = 262144,
    AssignmentType_StudentDiscussion = 524288,
    AssignmentType_StudentTalk = 1048576
};
```

This is the part of don't get:

```
int iFlag = MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType::AssignmentType_None;
for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < m_lbAssignmentsOCLM.GetCount(); iIndex++)
{
    if (m_lbAssignmentsOCLM.GetCheck(iIndex) == BST_CHECKED)
    {
        iFlag |= static_cast<MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType>(m_lbAssignmentsOCLM.GetItemData(iIndex));;
    }

}
theApp.WriteProfileInt(
    theApp.GetActiveScheduleSection(_T("Options")), _T("SRR_AssignmentsOCLM"), iFlag);
```

I had to use `int` for the `iFlag` variable. If I try to make that variable a `MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType` then the `|=` line will not work.

Yet, I **am** able to make calls like this to the API:

```
const COleDateTime datMeeting = GetMeetingDate(iRow);
auto eTypesToInclude = static_cast<MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType>(GetAssignmentsOCLMFlag());
CStringArray aryStrMeetingPersonnel;
theApp.MSAToolsInterface().GetPersonnelForMeeting(
    datMeeting,
    theApp.GetAssignHistoryPathEx(), 
    eTypesToInclude, aryStrMeetingPersonnel);
```

In short, why is it OK to pass the combined flag values as a `MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType` to a function in the API, but I had to use an `int` to build the compiled flags value first.

Make sense?

Comment: Because enum as flags is a pain in C++ ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448396/how-to-use-enums-as-flags-in-c

Comment: @SimonMourier One of those answers was very useful (about using `DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS` macro). Mint!