# Enum class bitwise operator overloading for reference type

Tags: c++, enums, casting, operator-overloading, static-cast

Tested my code here:

https://godbolt.org/z/Pb9nhq6jE

I have an enum defined like this.

```
enum Color
{
    Red = 0 << 0,
    Blue = 1 << 0,
    Green = 2 << 0,
};
```

I want to overload one of the bitwise operators

```
Color& operator |= (Color& a, Color b)
```

These two overloads work as expected

```
Color& operator |= (Color& a, Color b)
{ 
    return (Color&)((int&)a |= (int)(b)); 
}
```

```
Color& operator |= (Color& a, Color b)
{ 
    a = static_cast<Color>(static_cast<int64_t>(a) | static_cast<int64_t>(b));
    return a;
}
```

However, if I do the following way, the compiler complains
*:22:22: error: invalid 'static_cast' from type 'Color' to type 'int&'*

```
Color& operator |= (Color& a, Color b)
{ 
    return (Color&)((static_cast<int64_t&>(a)) |= (int64_t)(b)); 
}
```

But I am unsure why overloading works for c style casting (1st method) but compiler complains about static_cast.
As far as I understand, from compiler's standpoint, c-style casting and the static_cast keyword should basically compile the same way.

Comment: You cannot return a reference to a temporary or a local in a function (the reference will be dangling). You can return `Color` instead of `Color&`.

Comment: One difference is that "C style casting" will not tell you when it doesn't work! It is a "just do it anyway" command. This is one reason for C++ to have different casts, so you can tell the compiler what type you *really* want. And it can tell you if that is possible.

Comment: Also, for a plain enum you could use [std::underlying_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) to ask for the integer type to cast it to. `int64_t` is an unlikely compiler choice for just 3 values.

Comment: @BoP Do you mean that even if C-style implemenation compiles, it might fail runtime?

Comment: @BoP Good suggestion on std::underlying_type. I use 64 because this is just an example, real usage has much longer bitset. But I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, a C-style cast will do what you tell it to. Even when that is not possible (like writing 64 bits to a smaller variable)! "Odd things" can then happen at runtime.

Comment: @BoP https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152590/12997419
So this one should be downvoted?

Comment: That is an old answer, and it has a bunch of downvotes already.

Comment: As I found out the hard way, with `enum class Color : int{};` is not safe to treat a `Color` as a `int&`.  Doing so is **undefined behavior**.  You'll want to `static_cast` to/from the underlying type (`std::underlying_type_t`) as needed.

Comment: Also, why do you have `<< 0` for the enum values?  That doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Eljay Typo for 1 << 0, 1 << 1 etc. Yeah, I'll update my codebase to underlying_type today!