# Overloaded &= MACRO (to add functionality to enum) corrupts the stack

Tags: c++, c++builder

A long time ago, trying to improve readability on an existing project, certain defines were replaced by enums and the enums were 'enhanced' with overloaded operators to be able to combine the enums.

For instance:

```
enum Props
{
Prop_1 = 0x00000001,
Prop_2 = 0x00000002,
Prop_3 = 0x00000004,

Prop_4 = 0x00000100,

Prop_Group1 = 0x000000FF,
} ;

Props Properties = Prop_1 ; // Initial

Properties &= Prop_2 ; // For some reason we add another property
```

In my search to do this I was adviced to use following MACRO

```
#define MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS(ENUMTYPE) \
inline ENUMTYPE operator | (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((DWORD)a) | ((DWORD)b)); }           \
inline ENUMTYPE &operator |= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((DWORD &)a) |= ((DWORD)b)); }    \
inline ENUMTYPE operator & (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((DWORD)a) & ((DWORD)b)); }           \
inline ENUMTYPE &operator &= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((DWORD &)a) &= ((DWORD)b)); }    \
inline ENUMTYPE operator ~ (ENUMTYPE a)                 { return ENUMTYPE(~((DWORD)a)); }                       \
inline ENUMTYPE operator ^ (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((DWORD)a) ^ ((DWORD)b)); }           \
inline ENUMTYPE &operator ^= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((DWORD &)a) ^= ((DWORD)b)); }    \
```

so, by also applying the MACRO in the header:

```
MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS(Props)
```

This has actually always worked really well across many versions of Borland / CodeGear and Embarcadero C++ Builder, so I never looked at it again

Today I was dealing with a situation that could benefit from this functionality and the enum had many possible states, more than 32, so I figured I change the MACRO to cast to 64bit variables instead of 32 bit variables (one MACRO fits all)

Like so:

```
typedef unsigned __int64 UI64 ;

#define MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS(ENUMTYPE) \
inline ENUMTYPE operator | (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((UI64)a) | ((UI64)b)); }         \
inline ENUMTYPE &operator |= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((UI64 &)a) |= ((UI64)b)); }  \
inline ENUMTYPE operator & (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((UI64)a) & ((UI64)b)); }         \
inline ENUMTYPE &operator &= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((UI64 &)a) &= ((UI64)b)); }  \
inline ENUMTYPE operator ~ (ENUMTYPE a)                 { return ENUMTYPE(~((UI64)a)); }                    \
inline ENUMTYPE operator ^ (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((UI64)a) ^ ((UI64)b)); }         \
inline ENUMTYPE &operator ^= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((UI64 &)a) ^= ((UI64)b)); }  \
```

That was a mistake as the code started crashing due to corrupted variables, in combination with older enums with far less possible values

Noticed in following situation (example)

```
void Function (void *Input1, Props Properties, bool Whatever)
{
Properties &= Prop_Group1 ; // Corrupts Input1
// ..
}
```

I noticed Input1 was set to NULL instead of the value that had been passed to the function

I now realize the MACRO was never 100% safe to begin with !
Especially `&=`, `|=` and `^=`

All enums (using the MACRO) must be 4 bytes on the stack or problems may occur (Using the old DWORD cast MACRO).  That actually is probably the case since I tend to write = `0x00000000`.
**It's certainly time for a review**

And so when I changed to a 64bit type MACRO all the enums in use so far occupied 4 bytes on the stack, leading to problems.

I feel the MACRO can be made safer but I'd like your input to make sure I don't come to another 'aha' (or 'oh shit') moment 10 years down the line

Comment: If you are using C++, use C++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152590/4342498

Comment: That does come with the caveat that the code needs SFINAE or a requires cluase to limit the templates to enum types, but that is farily trivial to add, like `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, bool> = true> inline T operator~ (T a) { return (T)~(size_t)a; }`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you but your example casts to an int& and essentially has the same problem.  The enum **must** occupy 4 bytes or problems can occur

Comment: The problems come in if the enum and the integral type have different sizes (and cause undefined behaviour in `operator&=()` in some cases e.g. due to overwriting more bits than the enum has).    Assuming you want the code to work with all enums (as long as they don't exceed 64 bits) introduce a temporary rather than trying to do the bit fiddling in place   e.g. `ENUMTYPE &operator &= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  {a = ENUMTYPE((UI64)a & (UI64)b); return a;}`.    The limitation of this is losing bits if `ENUMTYPE` is larger than `UI64`.

Comment: Instead of casting explicitly to `UI64` you could cast to `std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>` so that you always use a correctly sized type for the enum you're using.

Comment: @MilesBudnek   That's a good option for C++14 and later.   If the OP requires backward compatibility to older compilers (the question mentioned older versions of Borland/Embacadero C++) then C++14 can't be assumed.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question suitable for Stack Overflow.  For peer review try [codereview.se].

Comment: @DavidJones It seems to me a lot of inexperienced developers, as I did once, could easily fall in this pit and then once they start seeing issues, this question could lead them to some answers quickly. Just my 5c.  I was not sure to post this or not anyway.  I figured I'd use (other) Peter's solution, but wanted to see if there are better ways to deal with this.

Comment: @Peter "I feel the MACRO can be made safer but I'd like your input to make sure" looks like a request for peer review to me.  If you feel you have a genuine question that others could benefit from please do post a suitable question and feel free to answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up 'fixing' the problem, based on the comments posted to my Question (for which I thank you).

PS. I currently use two compiler versions, one that supports c++ 11 and one that supports c++ 17.  The `#ifdef` reflects this, if you use a compiler that sits in the middle you will have to adjust for it.  In my case anything that goes out to 'the world' is built using the latest, so I worry less about the old compiler.

```
// https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Predefined_Macros#C.2B.2B_Compiler_Versions_in_Predefined_Macros
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695203/overloaded-macro-to-add-functionality-to-enum-corrupts-the-stack

#if defined(__BCPLUSPLUS__) && (__BCPLUSPLUS__ >= 0x0760) // >= C++ Builder 11

    // One MACRO fits all

    #define MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS(ENUMTYPE) \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator | (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)a) | ((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)b)); }         \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator |= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE> &)a) |= ((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)b)); }  \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator & (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)a) & ((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)b)); }         \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator &= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE> &)a) &= ((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)b)); }  \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator ~ (ENUMTYPE a)                 { return ENUMTYPE(~((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)a)); }                                                \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator ^ (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)a) ^ ((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)b)); }         \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator ^= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE> &)a) ^= ((std::underlying_type_t<ENUMTYPE>)b)); }  \

    #define MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS_DWORD     MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS
    #define MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS_UI64      MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS

#else

    // One MACRO fits all
    // Use tmp value for &=, |= and ^=
    // Enums cannot exceed 8 bytes for this MACRO to work !

    #define MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS_GEN(ENUMTYPE) \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator | (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((UI64)a) | ((UI64)b)); }         \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator |= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { a = ENUMTYPE((UI64)a | (UI64)b); return a; }      \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator & (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((UI64)a) & ((UI64)b)); }         \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator &= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { a = ENUMTYPE((UI64)a & (UI64)b); return a; }      \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator ~ (ENUMTYPE a)                 { return ENUMTYPE(~((UI64)a)); }                    \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator ^ (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((UI64)a) ^ ((UI64)b)); }         \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator ^= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { a = ENUMTYPE((UI64)a ^ (UI64)b); return a; }      \

    // Enums *must* be 4 bytes for following MACRO to work !
    // Otherwise the MACRO can corrupt the stack
    // Make sure no values are bigger than 0xFFFFFFFF
    // Optionally use syntax: typedef enum: DWORD { } Name ;

    #define MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS_DWORD(ENUMTYPE) \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator | (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((DWORD)a) | ((DWORD)b)); }           \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator |= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((DWORD &)a) |= ((DWORD)b)); }    \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator & (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((DWORD)a) & ((DWORD)b)); }           \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator &= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((DWORD &)a) &= ((DWORD)b)); }    \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator ~ (ENUMTYPE a)                 { return ENUMTYPE(~((DWORD)a)); }                       \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator ^ (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((DWORD)a) ^ ((DWORD)b)); }           \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator ^= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((DWORD &)a) ^= ((DWORD)b)); }    \

    // Enums *must* be 8 bytes for following MACRO to work !
    // Otherwise the MACRO can corrupt the stack
    // Best make sure there is a value higher than 0xFFFFFFFF
    // Optionally use syntax: typedef enum: UI64 { } Name ;

    #define MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS_UI64(ENUMTYPE) \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator | (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((UI64)a) | ((UI64)b)); }         \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator |= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((UI64 &)a) |= ((UI64)b)); }  \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator & (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((UI64)a) & ((UI64)b)); }         \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator &= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((UI64 &)a) &= ((UI64)b)); }  \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator ~ (ENUMTYPE a)                 { return ENUMTYPE(~((UI64)a)); }                    \
    inline ENUMTYPE operator ^ (ENUMTYPE a, ENUMTYPE b)     { return ENUMTYPE(((UI64)a) ^ ((UI64)b)); }         \
    inline ENUMTYPE &operator ^= (ENUMTYPE &a, ENUMTYPE b)  { return (ENUMTYPE &)(((UI64 &)a) ^= ((UI64)b)); }  \

    // Default to the DWORD version

    #define MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS       MY_DEFINE_ENUM_FLAG_OPERATORS_DWORD

#endif
```

Comment: Rather than testing Borland-specific macros, might be better to check standard macros (e.g. `__cplusplus` which expands to a value corresponding to the C++ standard the implementation claims to support).